# How do we test a div is hidden or not with the help of togglebutton in robot tests

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, robotframework

I have created a toggle button which holds a webcomponent with a text field and text area. I can hide this webcomponent, but when I tried to test it using robot testing and  Page Should Contain Element

```
locator = ${basePath}.querySelector("div[class='classname']")
```

Test is failing .Do I have any other alternatives other than "Page Should Contain Element" for testing the hidden div component?

Comment: When you say "Test is failing"... what is happening exactly, can you share an error you are getting?

Comment: depends on how you hide it... do you remove it from the DOM, or just set a style?  A locator will throw element does not exist if it's not there... if it's there it won't.. (though findElements() will just return an empty array if it doesn't exist)  When you interact with it it may throw "not interactable" or something like that.  The webdriver's exceptions will tell you what you need to know.  WebElements also have methods that return isDisplayed, etc... https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html